# modifying least significant bits in double (Java and C++)

Tags: java, c++, double

How to set to zero N least significant bits of a double in Java and C++?

In my computations, the "...002" in 1699.3000000000002, is caused by numerical error, so I would like to eliminate it.

Comment: Do you mean the **bits** of the binary representation or the **digits** of the decimal representation. I suspect the latter, although the word bits suggests the former. For example 0.3 doesn't need to be representable exactly (in binary representation) and also doesn't need to have all zeros at the end. Look at the link in Alex's comment for more insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `1e-12*Math.rint(1e12*x)` will round a double and return a double as the result.

In C++, you can write `1e-12*floor(1e12*x + 0.5)`.

Note, however, that these behave differently if 10<sup>12</sup>*x* is exactly between two integers. The Java version will round towards an even number, whereas the C++ version will always round upwards.

Comment: Thanks! Is there similar method in Java? In Java Math.round() converts double into long.

Comment: Why on earth did I think this was a Python question? Anyway, I've amended my answer to suit the question better.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that you are actually doing currency calculations. In which case using a binary data type like `double` is probably the root cause of your problems. Switch to a decimal type and you should be able to side-step such issues.

Comment: Also highly recommend reading "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768

Comment: I do use integers for this type of data. That was a problem of printing the result, which is converted back to double by multiplying by minimal increment. Thanks.